# How often does parthenogenesis in mammals happen?

Tags: reproduction, development, embryology

Probably everyone knows that mammals can't produce viable offspring by parthenogenesis.

But there are reports of human chimeras (see: [a human parthenogenetic chimaera](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7550344)) and it's known for mice to quite often develop parthenogenetic embryos that will not survive past the 10th day of gestation (see: [birth of parthenogenetic mice that can develop to adulthood](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15103378)).

So, how often does parthenogenesis happen in mammals and how long do parthenogenetic embryos survive? I have heard an estimate that 0.01% of human blastocystes are parthenogenetic with gestations always ending in miscarriage before the 3rd month, but I couldn't find any source for this claim.